# How can I cancel performSelectorOnMainThread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsthread

How can I cancel `performSelectorOnMainThread`?

I have this code:

```
myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

[myClass performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setupPlayer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a legit question.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're careful about the thread on which you originally queued the message, you **can** cancel it by calling `+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget` on that same thread. That previous answer was missing an important bit:

> You cannot cancel messages queued using this method. If you want the
>   option of canceling a message on the current thread, you must use
>   either the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: or
>   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes: method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF):

> You cannot cancel messages queued using this method.

Comment: This answer is misleading; you **can** cancel a queued message by calling `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` on the same thread. See my answer below.

Comment: @samvermette: You can cancel messages if both the target and caller are on the same thread. You can **not** if the target or caller is on a different thread, which is what the OP was asking.

Comment: @EvanMulawski I hadn't noticed that the code in the OP was specifically targeting the **main** thread, but even then the correct answer is that you **can** cancel it as long as you call `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` from the main thread.